# Access webform select list key from within rules

Tags: 7, rules, webforms

I have a webform that needs to be sent via rules. That's all fine but I don't seem to be able to access the data key for a select list in my webform.

I can get the value like this:

```
[data:location-value]
```

But I need to key not tha value.

I tried (as a guess)

```
[data:location-key]
```

But that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used a work-a-round for this by using the translate option in Drupal.

I've set up the key as a value and translated the key to the value that I wanted.

This was used for a custom field, but it worked fine for me.